# Startup-Linkage in Windows

Tags: c++

The ELF-format, which linux uses to store programs, allows you to dynamically link functions through a resolver function returning the function-pointer, when the program is started up. In machine code there is no need to load the address of the function, instead the new linked address is directly inlined to the call-instruction. In GCC/Clang you can do:

```
#include <iostream>

using TheFunc = void(*)();

// the resolver function is declared with extern"C",
// so you do not have to use the mangeled name as
// parameter to ifunc
extern"C" TheFunc thefunc_resolve() {
    // maybe select a specific target function
    return +[]{ std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; };
}

void thefunc() __attribute((ifunc("thefunc_resolve")));

int main() {
    thefunc();

    return 0;
};
```

THE QUESTION: Is there any possible way to do the same linkage in a Windows binary, without assembler hacking or just calling a function pointer (which is much slower, because of the load of the pointer from a variable)?

Comment: The PE32 format permits exporting data as well, not otherwise limited to function pointers.  Just give it the dllexport attribute in the DLL source, dllimport in the client header.  Binding at runtime works the same as it does on *nix.

Comment: *which is much slower, because of the load of the pointer from a variable* [citation needed]. I have yet to witness any performance problem coming from an indirect call itself (either due to a jump through IAT/PLT or to virtual functions, which is essentially the same); the rare performance problems connected with these usually come at most from the missed opportunity of inlining (and only for extremely small functions), not from the indirect jump.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, look up delay-loaded DLLs. It can even be done with a custom resolution function.

Comment: Expand your answer please. Otherwise, it could be flagged as NAA/VLQ.